# cocos2dx 3.3 animation implementation

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android, cocos2d-js

I am new in cocos2dx development.I almost learn all basic level of cocos2dx (version 3.3) in android using cpp language. I showing that there are lots of update over cocos2dx.org.

In android I am currently developing the tetris game using cocos2dx version 3.3, I want to know what is the best way to achieve awesome animation such like ticking bombs, bomb explosion, spinning game score display, popping up and disappearing balloons with game score increments. I was wondering about animation implementation cocos2dx in android using c++. We also need to make game that support the multiscreen support, I had search lots all these points could not able to find much information over the google.

I show sonar system support nicely for beginner level, we really appreciate it , I had watched all videos shared by sonar system over the YouTube. I learn lot over there. I want to know the advance level animation in android in cocos2dx.

We looking any help will appreciate.

Thank you

Comment: have you done multiscreen support ?

Comment: could not able to done, but we was getting the help from another game development company, the developers suggested to used the scaling factor. they actually develop the  iPhone game using cocos2dx then porting to the android. They said the easy way to give the support other platform.

Comment: i have done it... it was lenghty .. if you want then i can share my classes ...

Comment: Please sure can you share Any help is appreciate

Comment: Actually we fond that cocos2dx provide the different bucket folder (such like mdpi,hpdi,xhdpi,xxhdpi) for pick up the correct resource. It work fine but the scale is not auto done.

Comment: As you know android did apply the auto scaling.

Comment: i added another answer you can check .. it may help .. i did like this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my appmacros.h filr ..

```
#ifndef __APPMACROS_H__
#define __APPMACROS_H__

#include "cocos2d.h"



#define DESIGN_RESOLUTION_480X320    0
#define DESIGN_RESOLUTION_480X800    1
#define DESIGN_RESOLUTION_1024X768   2
#define DESIGN_RESOLUTION_1280X800   3
#define DESIGN_RESOLUTION_2048X1536  4

/* If you want to switch design resolution, change next line */
#define TARGET_DESIGN_RESOLUTION_SIZE  DESIGN_RESOLUTION_1280X800

typedef struct tagResource
{
    cocos2d::CCSize size;
    char directory[100];
}Resource;

static Resource smallResource  =  { CCSizeMake(480, 320),   "iphone" };
static Resource mysmallResource  =  { CCSizeMake(800, 480),   "iphone" };
static Resource mediumResource =  { CCSizeMake(1024, 768),  "ipad"   };
static Resource myResource =  { CCSizeMake(1280, 800),  "ipad" };
static Resource largeResource  =  { CCSizeMake(2048, 1536), "ipadhd" };

#if (TARGET_DESIGN_RESOLUTION_SIZE == DESIGN_RESOLUTION_480X320)
static cocos2d::CCSize designResolutionSize = cocos2d::CCSizeMake(480, 320);
#elif (TARGET_DESIGN_RESOLUTION_SIZE == DESIGN_RESOLUTION_480X800)
static cocos2d::CCSize designResolutionSize = cocos2d::CCSizeMake(800, 480);
#elif (TARGET_DESIGN_RESOLUTION_SIZE == DESIGN_RESOLUTION_1024X768)
static cocos2d::CCSize designResolutionSize = cocos2d::CCSizeMake(1024, 768);
#elif (TARGET_DESIGN_RESOLUTION_SIZE == DESIGN_RESOLUTION_2048X1536)
static cocos2d::CCSize designResolutionSize = cocos2d::CCSizeMake(2048, 1536);
#elif (TARGET_DESIGN_RESOLUTION_SIZE == DESIGN_RESOLUTION_1280X800)
static CCSize designResolutionSize = cocos2d::CCSizeMake(1280, 800);
#else
#error unknown target design resolution!
#endif

// The font size 24 is designed for small resolution, so we should change it to fit for current design resolution
#define TITLE_FONT_SIZE  (cocos2d::CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView()->getDesignResolutionSize().width / myResource.size.width * 24)

#endif /* __APPMACROS_H__ */
```

now we can use this class in appdelegate.. so my appdelegate looks like...

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "MenuLayer.h"
#include "AppMacros.h"
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"


USING_NS_CC;


AppDelegate::AppDelegate() {

}

AppDelegate::~AppDelegate() {

}
void AppDelegate::initGLContextAttrs()
{
    //set OpenGL context attributions,now can only set six attributions:
    //red,green,blue,alpha,depth,stencil
    GLContextAttrs glContextAttrs = {8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 8};

    GLView::setGLContextAttrs(glContextAttrs);
}

bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {

    // initialize director
    auto director = Director::getInstance();
    auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();
    if(!glview) {
        glview = GLViewImpl::create("My Game");
        director->setOpenGLView(glview);
    }

    CCLOG("%s","applicationDidFinishLaunching ");
    // initialize director
//  CCDirector* pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
//  CCEGLView* pEGLView = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();

    director->setOpenGLView(glview);

    // Set the design resolution
    glview->setDesignResolutionSize(designResolutionSize.width,
            designResolutionSize.height, kResolutionFixedWidth);

    //CCSize frameSize = pEGLView->getFrameSize();
    CCSize frameSize = director->getVisibleSize();

    // if the frame's height is larger than the height of medium resource size, select large resource.
    if (frameSize.width > myResource.size.width) {

        director->setContentScaleFactor(
                largeResource.size.width / designResolutionSize.width);

    }
    // if the frame's height is larger than the height of small resource size, select medium resource.
    else if (frameSize.width > mediumResource.size.width) {

        director->setContentScaleFactor(
                myResource.size.width / designResolutionSize.width);

    } else if (frameSize.width > mysmallResource.size.width) {

        director->setContentScaleFactor(
                designResolutionSize.width / mediumResource.size.width);

    } else if (frameSize.width > smallResource.size.width) {

        director->setContentScaleFactor(
                designResolutionSize.width / mediumResource.size.width);

    }
    // if the frame's height is smaller than the height of medium resource size, select small resource.
    else {

        director->setContentScaleFactor(
                designResolutionSize.width / smallResource.size.width);

    }

    // turn on display FPS
    director->setDisplayStats(false);

    // set FPS. the default value is 1.0/60 if you don't call this
    director->setAnimationInterval(1.0 / 60);


    CCScene *pScene = MenuLayer::scene();


    director->runWithScene(pScene);



    return true;
}

// This function will be called when the app is inactive. When comes a phone call,it's be invoked too
void AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground() {
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->stopAnimation();

    // if you use SimpleAudioEngine, it must be pause
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->pauseBackgroundMusic();


}

// this function will be called when the app is active again
void AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground() {
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->startAnimation();

    // if you use SimpleAudioEngine, it must resume here
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->resumeBackgroundMusic();


}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code It will try this, let me know "iphone" "iphone" this is the resource directory for iPhone can i declare the "hdpi" "mdpi" for android

Comment: It is working fine, can you tell me where i need to put the all resources images for android.

Comment: currently we put the images in different bucket folder.

Comment: put all tha game related images in assets folder and put icons in different drawables folder under res directory..

Comment: Hi can you tell me "TARGET_DESIGN_RESOLUTION_SIZE " actually i define high resolution now when i run on my device it is hdpi device it look fine it visible size change to target design size

Comment: In this code we have to define the target design still when i test in another device it not display the hello world test on correct place

Comment: #define TARGET_DESIGN_RESOLUTION_SIZE  DESIGN_RESOLUTION_1280X800 here DESIGN_RESOLUTION is the size of your assest size (define it according to your design resolution )

Answer (score 1):

i am also new to cocos2dx 3.3 . well i am using animation for blast (explosion) by using (.plist) particle effects 
first  you need a .plist file of animation . there is a online editor for making .plist file . you can check it out 
here is link . http://www.effecthub.com/particle2dx

now  you can use thiese line of code

```
CCParticleSystemQuad *system = CCParticleSystemQuad::create("explodeEffect.plist");

system->setTexture(CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("yourplayer.png"));
system->setDuration(0.05);
system->setScale(3.0f);
 system->setPosition(yourplayer->getPosition().x, yourplayer->getPosition().y);
this->addChild(system,1);
system->setAutoRemoveOnFinish(true);
```

this will help you